# Check if a column exists Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

How to check if a column exists in query builder Codeigniter 3?
Example :

```
$query = $this->db->coluln_exists('column_name', 'table_name');
if($query == TRUE)
{
return TRUE;
} 
else
{
return FALSE;}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `field_exists` instead of `coluln_exists` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
if ($this->db->field_exists('field_name', 'table_name'))
{
        // some code...
}
```

> You can see complete description [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/metadata.html#determine-if-a-field-is-present-in-a-table).